# Showing that a sequence of random variables with $\mathcal{L}(X_{n})$ (I.e., law) uniform on $[-n,n]$ does not converge at all

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real valued random variables with $\mathcal{L}(X_{n})$ (that is, law or distribution) uniform on $[-n,n]$. In what sense(s) do $X_{n}$ converge to a random variable $X$?

We are told that the answer is none. To prove this, are we supposed to show that $X_{n}$ does not converge under the weakest form of convergence possible (convergence in distribution/law)? And if we do, is that sufficient to show that there is no convergence? Also, how does the fact that the r.v.'s are uniformly distributed give us that?

Comment: You can see various implications of types of convergence here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables (the first diagram under the Properties header). So, yes, it is sufficient to show it does not converge in distribution.

Comment: To show it does not converge in distribution, you might want to investigate limiting behavior of the Uniform$[-n,n]$ cdf.

Comment: $ F(x)= \begin{cases}0&\text{if $x<-n$}\\\frac{x+2n}{2n}&\text{if $x\in[-n,n)$} \\1&\text{if $x\geq n$.}\end{cases}$. $\\$ What do you mean by limiting behavior?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $x+n$, not $x+2n$? In any case, what happens to that as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence in distribution means

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x)$$

where the RHS is a distribution function, and the equality to hold for every $x$ for which  $F_X(x)$ is continuous.
Our distribution function is

$$F_{X_n}(x)= \begin{cases}0&\text{if $x<-n$}\\\frac{x+n}{2n}&\text{if $x\in[-n,n]$} \\1&\text{if $x> n$.}\end{cases}$$

The first and the last branch are not defined as $n\rightarrow \infty$, since there is no $x$ lower than "minus infinity", or higher than "plus infinity". Then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big (\frac{x}{2n} + \frac 12\Big) = 0+\frac 12$$

The constant function $1/2$ does not satisfy the [properties of a distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties), specifically

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac 12 =\frac 12 \neq 0,\;\;\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac 12 =\frac 12 \neq 1$$
Carefully note that $n$ and $x$ do *not* "go together" at plus/minus infinity. To study convergence we first "send $n$ to infinity", and *then* we examine the behavior of the limiting function we have obtained, as its argument passes over.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is uniform on $[-1,1]$, then $nU$ is uniform on $[-n,n]$. We have for each $t$,
$$\mathbb P(nU\leqslant t)=\mathbb P(U\leqslant t/n)\to 1/2,$$
since the cumulative distribution function of $U$ is continuous at $0$.

This proves that $(nU)_n$ cannot converge in distribution.

Comment: Would you mind explaining for me why having a continuous cdf at $X=0$ means $X_{n}$ cannot converge in distribution?

Comment: The fact that $U$ has a cdf continuous at $0$ proves the assertion in the displayed line. If you have a sequence of random variables such that for each $t$, $\mathbb P(X_n\leqslant t)\to$ a constant independent of $t$, we can't have convergence in dsitribution. This would indeed converge to $F(t)$, the cdf of the potential limit, at all but countably many $t$'s, hence $F$ would be constant, which is not possible.